# NetSuite SuiteScript 2.0 getSelectOptions filter breaks setValue

Tags: netsuite

I am dumbfounded on what is happening and hoping someone can help me figure out what is happening. I am using SuiteScript 2.0 and to find the internal id's of dynamic fields I am doing:

```
var location = saleRec.getField({
    fieldId: 'location'
}).getSelectOptions({
    filter: "Test Location",
    operator: 'is'
});
```

This returns the internal ID I need but when I try to call:

```
saleRec.setValue({
    fieldId: 'location',
    value: location[0].value
});
```

I get an error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "JS_EXCEPTION",
    "message": "{\"type\":\"error.SuiteScriptError\",\"name\":\"INVALID_FLD_VALUE\",\"message\":\"You have entered an Invalid Field Value 2 for the following field: location\",\"stack\":[\"anonymous(N/recordService)\",\"doPost(SuiteScripts/DemoProject/RESTlet1.js:124)\"],\"cause\":{\"type\":\"internal error\",\"code\":\"INVALID_FLD_VALUE\",\"details\":\"You have entered an Invalid Field Value 2 for the following field: location\",\"userEvent\":null,\"stackTrace\":[\"anonymous(N/recordService)\",\"doPost(SuiteScripts/DemoProject/RESTlet1.js:124)\"]},\"id\":\"\"}"
  }
}
```

The number 2 is definitely the internal ID I need. But it starts to get weird. If I remove the filter and just call:

```
var location = saleRec.getField({
    fieldId: 'location'
}).getSelectOptions();
```

And then loop through the array of results and select the proper internal id I need everything works fine and it is able to set the internal id of `location`. It seems like the filter is removing it from the `location` select field or something strange like that but I can't imagine that is the intended purpose of the filter. Is this a bug or am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch, try running again

.getSelectOptions({filter: "Test Location",operator: 'is'}).

Then after getting the value

.getSelectOptions();

It seems like a bug, where the data object holding the available values is left filtered.